# 18.04 LTS LSI RAID UEFI boot issues

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, raid

System config:

- Gigabyte GA-H61M-HD2 4 GB RAM
- Intel SRCSAS144e (LSI 8344elp) HW RAID
  w/BBU
- 3x 4 TB SATA drives in RAID5
- 18.04 LTS UEFI install

The RAID5 will be degraded randomly on boot. It's usually a random single drive out of the 3, and so far I've always been able to rebuild it, but I'm trying to determine why it fails.

The Intel/LSI RAID util on boot will usually indicate that there's a foreign configuration and ask to import it. Even then, there's usually a drive that is `UNCONF BAD`. If I mark it `UNCONF GOOD` I'm then able to import the foreign configuration, at which point the failed drive starts rebuilding. If it were the same drive failing, it would be suspect, but it varies.

I was unable to install Ubuntu on the 8TB drive until I created a small partition for /boot, which shouldn't have been necessary under UEFI. I was able to successfully install, but would always get `error: attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0` on the first reboot.

I've replaced the RAID controller, and all firmware is up to date, both on the motherboard & controller, so it's unlikely the issue is the controller, especially given it's the ancient but tried-and-true LSI 1068e chipset.

I suspect that the system is somehow overwriting the RAID configuration that is written to the disks. How can I avoid this?

I'm open to other explanations, and most importantly, solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible data "corruption":**

LSI 1068E can use at most 2.2TB of a disk, which is apparently a hardware limitation. This could explain you seeing problems with RAID.

**Unable to boot from a LSI 1068E based controller:**

These  controllers usually lack EFI Option ROM, which is required for booting under UEFI. You can flash one using `sasflash -o -b [file]` under Linux.

**Side notes:**

- This controller adds ~20 seconds to boot time.
- Opinionated suggestion: Switch from hardware RAID to Linux Software RAID (the latter is continuously developed whereas hardware implementation..not so much).

  - In 1068E case, there are two firmware variants. One is "IT", which passes drives directly to the OS. The other variant is "IR", which has hardware RAID capabilities.

Sorry if this didn't answer your question directly.

---

- [sasflash](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12350825)
  `Installer_P21_for_Linux.zip`
  Version: 1.30.00.00
- [EFI Option ROM](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12350157)
  `EFI_BSD_PH_21-3-22-00-00.zip`
  Version: 3.22.00.00
- [Firmware and BIOS Option ROM](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12351271)
  `SAS3801E_-Package_P21_IR_IT_Firmware_BIOS_for_MSDOS_Windows.zip`
  Version: Firmware: 01.33.00.00; BIOS (option rom): 6.36.00.00